# how to change default sort by price to custom attribute like gtin in magento 2

Tags: php, database, magento2.3

i have already tried to make the chanage of sort by price to custom attribute in admin store configuration but still the products are sorting by price in magento 2

Answer (score 2):

Make sure Gtin attribute set as use in `product sorting` to `Yes` in `Store  > Attribute` add edit Gtin attribute and check this

change `Store > Configuration  > Catalog  >  Storefront > Product Listing Sort By` to `Gtin`

also got to `Catalog  >  Manage Category` and edit the category in which you want to change sorting and make sure here `Default Product Listing Sort By` option set to `Gtin`